# Trim All Cells of a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a `DataTable` that is filled using an SQL query. If the values of this `DataTable` are not trimmed (from both left and right), the program is unable to find correct matches. So I am looking for an efficient LINQ query (not two nested `foreach` statements) to trim all the values in the `DataTable` and return a clean version of it.

Comment: Wouldn't the nested foreach statements be nice and clean, why do you have to have LINQ?

Comment: Wouldn't trimming in the DB be the better ie more efficient solution? LINQ will certainly not be more __efficient__ than a loop, just more stylish..

Comment: When you attempt to match you could trim at that point

Comment: @TaW not when you don't know what your query is going to be. Or is there a way to trim all values regardless of query?

Comment: @jradich1234 that is true but getting rid of all unnecessary spaces in the beginning is more convenient, I suppose.

Comment: Hm, that sounds very mysterious; unless you want to the obnoxious `select * from sometable;`

Comment: Let me add the obvious: If your DB data need sanitizing make sure to do it or have it done; also make sure the sources of the paddings get stomped out as well..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient way is to do that in the database, f.e.:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(ColumnName)) AS TrimmedColumn FROM TableName
```

If you must do it with C# the most performant way is a simple loop (LINQ also uses loops):

```
DataColumn[] stringColumns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(c => c.DataType == typeof(string))
    .ToArray();

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
   foreach(DataColumn col in stringColumns)
      row.SetField<string>(col, row.Field<string>(col).Trim());
```

In general, don't use LINQ to *modify* the source. A query should not cause side-effects.

Comment: Thanks! I will use your solution instead of LINQ.

Comment: To prevent null reference errors add `if( row[column] != DBNull.Value )`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can apply a LINQ Select statement on a DataTable and use the Trim() on the String class to achieve your goal. But as a Database Developer I would suggest acting on the SQL Query and use the Rtrim(Ltrim(field1)) AS field1 on your query to get rid of the spaces before the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions method for datatable:

```
 public static void trimData(DataTable dt)
 {
            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
                if (c.DataType == typeof(string))
                    foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                        try
                        {
                            r[c.ColumnName] = r[c.ColumnName].ToString().Trim();
                        }
                        catch
                        { }
 }
```

for dataset:

```
public static void trimData(DataSet ds)
{
     foreach (DataTable t in ds.Tables)
       trimData(t);
}
```